# creating itemsets in apriori algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, merge, set

I am reading about association analysis in book titled Machine learning in action. Following code is given in book

> The k-2 thing may be a little confusing. Let’s look at that a little
>   further. When you were creating {0,1} {0,2}, {1,2} from {0}, {1}, {2},
>   you just combined items. Now, what if you want to use {0,1} {0,2},
>   {1,2} to create a three-item set? If you did the union of every set,
>   you’d get {0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2}. That’s right. It’s the same
>   set three times. Now you have to scan through the list of three-item
>   sets to get only unique values. You’re trying to keep the number of
>   times you go through the lists to a minimum. Now, if you compared the
>   first element {0,1} {0,2}, {1,2} and only took the union of those that
>   had the same first item, what would you have? {0, 1, 2} just one time.
>   Now you don’t have to go through the list looking for unique values.

```
def aprioriGen(Lk, k): #creates Ck
    retList = []
    lenLk = len(Lk)
    for i in range(lenLk):
        for j in range(i+1, lenLk):
            L1 = list(Lk[i])[:k-2]; L2 = list(Lk[j])[:k-2] # Join sets if first k-2 items are equal
            L1.sort(); L2.sort()
            if L1==L2:
                retList.append(Lk[i] | Lk[j])
    return retLis
```

Suppose i am calling above function

```
Lk = [frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({3, 5}), frozenset({2, 5}), frozenset({1, 3})]

k = 3

aprioriGen(Lk,3)
```

I am geting following output

```
[frozenset({2, 3, 5})]
```

I think there is bug in above logic since we are missing other combinations like {1,2,3}, {1,3,5}. Isn't it? Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are following the below link, Output set depends on the minSupport what we pass.

http://adataanalyst.com/machine-learning/apriori-algorithm-python-3-0/

If we reduce the minSupport value to 0.2, we get all sets.

Below is the complete code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Dec 31 16:57:26 2018

@author: rponnurx
"""

from numpy import *

def loadDataSet():
    return [[1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [2, 5]]

def createC1(dataSet):
    C1 = []
    for transaction in dataSet:
        for item in transaction:
            if not [item] in C1:
                C1.append([item])

    C1.sort()
    return list(map(frozenset, C1))#use frozen set so we
                            #can use it as a key in a dict  

def scanD(D, Ck, minSupport):
    ssCnt = {}
    for tid in D:
        for can in Ck:
            if can.issubset(tid):
                if not can in ssCnt: ssCnt[can]=1
                else: ssCnt[can] += 1
    numItems = float(len(D))
    retList = []
    supportData = {}
    for key in ssCnt:
        support = ssCnt[key]/numItems
        if support >= minSupport:
            retList.insert(0,key)
        supportData[key] = support
    return retList, supportData

dataSet = loadDataSet()
print(dataSet)

C1 = createC1(dataSet)

print(C1)

#D is a dataset in the setform.

D = list(map(set,dataSet))
print(D)

L1,suppDat0 = scanD(D,C1,0.5)
print(L1)

def aprioriGen(Lk, k): #creates Ck
    retList = []
    print("Lk")
    print(Lk)
    lenLk = len(Lk)
    for i in range(lenLk):
        for j in range(i+1, lenLk): 
            L1 = list(Lk[i])[:k-2]; L2 = list(Lk[j])[:k-2]
            L1.sort(); L2.sort()
            if L1==L2: #if first k-2 elements are equal
                retList.append(Lk[i] | Lk[j]) #set union
    return retList

def apriori(dataSet, minSupport = 0.5):
    C1 = createC1(dataSet)
    D = list(map(set, dataSet))
    L1, supportData = scanD(D, C1, minSupport)

    L = [L1]
    k = 2
    while (len(L[k-2]) > 0):
        Ck = aprioriGen(L[k-2], k)
        Lk, supK = scanD(D, Ck, minSupport)#scan DB to get Lk
        supportData.update(supK)
        L.append(Lk)
        k += 1
    return L, supportData

L,suppData = apriori(dataSet,0.2)

print(L)
```

Output:
[[frozenset({5}), frozenset({2}), frozenset({4}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({1})], [frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({1, 5}), frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({3, 5}), frozenset({2, 5}), frozenset({1, 3}), frozenset({1, 4}), frozenset({3, 4})], [frozenset({1, 3, 5}), frozenset({1, 2, 3}), frozenset({1, 2, 5}), frozenset({2, 3, 5}), frozenset({1, 3, 4})], [frozenset({1, 2, 3, 5})], []]

Thanks,
Rajeswari Ponnuru

Comment: @ Thanks for answering. Still I am not getting  when we combine data for example from two element set to three element set we don't check for confidence yet, so we have to find all three elements sets Isn't it. For example {1,3} and  {3,5} are two elements sets which are to be combined to form {1,3,5} and then we check for confidence level before we decidie to use it for 4 element set or not. Isn't it?